# Can I get file extensions from a folder using php?

Tags: php

I have a register form from which I give name, last name and a photo and then I store name and last name in database but photo in a folder , `name+lastname.extension`

but when I want to display these profiles in website, I get name and lastname from database and img I want `name+lastname` but is there a way I can search first what is the extension of file in folder with name , `name+lastname`

because I want to access that image I need first to know the extension if it `png jpg` or something else ?

Comment: Its better to save file name along rest of form fields.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan do you mean , I save the file name in database ?

Comment: Yup. it could be te best way to save file name and easy to access and in `img` tag

Comment: yes indeed but the glob() function did the job pretty well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do like this

```
$result = glob ("name+lastname.*");
```

The $result will have your full file name.

OR

You can search with extensions

```
$result = glob("name+lastname.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)
```

Comment: how will it know in which folder to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function in php called pathinfo() and you can use it like this

`$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

That should be able to get the extension

Comment: $ext = pathinfo("img".$_SESSION['dept']."/".strtolower($emri.$mbiemri),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
I am using $_SESSION['dept'] to know which img folder to access and then/filename but I am not getting the extension , am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Imagine that $_SESSION['dept'] has value 'map1', then you are now trying to call

imgmap1/

so depending on how you store your values you might have to add another slash. I'm not sure how to specify your path as i can't know how you're storing the variables

Answer (score 1):

even better solution when you upload the image name it like this whatever.extension.extension example whatever.jpg.jpg by this little trick you can get the extension of any file u want with out specifying the extension for it since u will get it through the name

Answer (score 0):

This is better if you save them with one extension like PNG, but if you don't want that, try this:

```
$filename = 'name+lastname.';
if (file_exists($filename . 'png')) {
    echo "..."; // some HTML to show .png
} elseif (file_exists($filename . 'jpg')) {
    echo "..."; // some HTML to show .jpg
} else {
    echo "..."; // some HTML to show .gif
}
// and more
```